Discord.js Command Option Type?
I am making a discord bot with TypeScript.
I us an interface ICommand for referring to a discord command.
Also, I manually created another interface ICommandOption for referring to a discord command's options.
Is there any interface/type that is built to the discord.js package so I don't need to manually define it?
ICommandOption.ts:
export default interface ICommandOption {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    required: boolean;
    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType;
}

ICommand.ts:
export default interface ICommand {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    devOnly: boolean;
    testOnly: boolean;
    options?: ICommandOption[];
    permissionsRequired?: bigint[];
    deleted?: boolean; // Used to delete an existing command from the bot

    callback: (client: Client, interaction: CommandInteraction) => void;
}

I tried to search discord.js' docs, although I couldn't find any answer for this.

Personally I have used the discord-api-types package on NPM, using the RESTPostAPIApplicationCommandsJSONBody type. This replaces ICommandOption.
import type { RESTPostAPIApplicationCommandsJSONBody } from "discord-api-types/v10";

Since I can't see your command file, I'm not sure how you define your command options, so I'm guessing you are using SlashCommandBuilder() which it will work with.
